# Create a New Pandas column in df from multiple columns using different rules

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df

```
        SUITE      DET 
0       HISTO  HisRep2  
1       HISTO  HisRep3 
2         NaN    store  
3         NaN   OnHold 
4        PMFA   Nemato  
5    bactmate   Nemato 
6      bacto1   abbac4  
7   abbadabba   BhyCPC 
8      HAEMFF   pmbac3
9      INCLIN    Trico 
10     BOCOSP    isol1
```

I want to create a third column. The third column will hold a mix of data from the first two columns, using 3 criteria.

I have created code for the 3 criteria individually, but I want to do them simultaneously. My 3 bits are

1. Create the new column 'SUITEDET' and if the column 'SUITE' contains a Nan/is empty, fill in the new column using data from column 'DET'

```
df['SUITEDET'] = df[df['SUITE'].isnull()]['DET']
```

which makes df

```
        SUITE      DET SUITEDET
0       HISTO  HisRep2      NaN
1       HISTO  HisRep3      NaN
2         NaN    store    store
3         NaN   OnHold   OnHold
4        PMFA   Nemato      NaN
5    bactmate   Nemato      NaN
6      bacto1   abbac4      NaN
7   abbadabba   BhyCPC      NaN
8      HAEMFF   pmbac3      NaN
9      INCLIN    Trico      NaN
10     BOCOSP    isol1      NaN
```

2. Create the new column 'SUITEDET' and if the 'DET' column has entries in the list 'usedet',complete the new column using data from the column 'SUITE'

```
usedet = ['pmbac1','pmbac2','pmbac3','pmbac4','pmbac5','pmbac6','bact1','bact2','bact3','bact4','bact5','bact6','bactAdd1','bactAdd2','bactAdd3','abbac1','abbac2','abbac3','abbac4','abbac5','abbac6','BrachSmear','Brachy','Brachy1','Brachy10','Brachy2','Brachy3','Brachy4','Brachy5','Brachy6','Brachy7','Brachy8','Brachy9','BhyC','isol','salm1','salm2','salm3','salm4','pmavb1','pmavb2','pmavb3','pmavb4','pmavb5','pmavb6','pmavsh','pmavsp','cult','zncult','pmfoBK','pmfood','Coccn','Coccid','CoccidGoat','Strngy','StoidE','Stoide','Nemato','NematE','TrichE','Tricd','Tricm','Trico','Trics','Tricu','Monspp','Fecn','BhyC21','BhyCID','BhyCPC','BhyCPCTrig','BhyClt','isol1','isol1C','isol1F','isol1M','isol1S','isol2','isol2C','isol2F','isol2M','isol2S','isol3','isol3C','isol3F','isol3M','isol3S','isolA','isolB','isolC']

df['SUITEDET'] = df[df['DET'].isin(usedet)]['SUITE']
```

which creates df

```
        SUITE      DET   SUITEDET
0       HISTO  HisRep2        NaN
1       HISTO  HisRep3        NaN
2         NaN    store        NaN
3         NaN   Nemato        NaN
4        PMFA   BodyWt        PMFA
5    bactmate   Nemato   bactmate
6      bacto1   abbac4     bacto1
7   abbadabba   BhyCPC  abbadabba
8      HAEMFF   pmbac3     HAEMFF
9      INCLIN    Trico     INCLIN
10     BOCOSP    isol1     BOCOSP
```

3. Create the new column 'SUITEDET' and if the 'SUITE' column has entries in the list 'usesuite',complete the new column using data from the column 'SUITE'

```
usesuite = ["HAEMFF","HAEM4F","INCLIN","BOCOSP","OVCOSP","WECOCF","WECOCA","WECOCP","ECOPCR","BLKWEC","BLKWF","BLKFLK","FLKIND","WECFLK","BHYCULT","BHY21","INCH","LEPTMS","GSH-PX","HISTO","CHLEIAS","CHLEIAG","BVD","BVDANT","BVDAB","CLA","IBRMS","SINFAB","JMILKI","JMILKB","BVDMS","BVDIND","BVDPCR","SBVIMB","SBVIMI","RUMENE","FATLIV","DOWNER","BMMETP","FAMIN","OMETAP","BOVPRO","OPRODP","COPBLK","COPRO","RESPCR"]

df['SUITEDET'] = df[df['SUITE'].isin(usesuite)]['SUITE']
```

which makes df

```
        SUITE      DET SUITEDET
0       HISTO  HisRep2    HISTO
1       HISTO  HisRep3    HISTO
2         NaN    store      NaN
3         NaN   OnHold      NaN
4        PMFA   Nemato      NaN
5    bactmate   Nemato      NaN
6      bacto1   abbac4      NaN
7   abbadabba   BhyCPC      NaN
8      HAEMFF   pmbac3   HAEMFF
9      INCLIN    Trico   INCLIN
10     BOCOSP    isol1   BOCOSP
```

what I want to get out at the end is a df like this, where the third column is completed using the by using the three criteria to select the correct data from the first two columns

```
        SUITE      DET SUITEDET
0       HISTO  HisRep2    HISTO
1       HISTO  HisRep3    HISTO
2         NaN    store    store
3         NaN   OnHold    OnHold
4        PMFA   Nemato    PMFA
5    bactmate   Nemato    bactmate
6      bacto1   abbac4    bacto1
7   abbadabba   BhyCPC    abbadabba
8      HAEMFF   pmbac3    HAEMFF
9      INCLIN    Trico    INCLIN
10     BOCOSP    isol1    BOCOSP
```

Should I run the three criteria and create 3dfs and then try and merge them or is there a pythonic way to run the 3 bits together. I don't even need a specific answer if it's a hassle, just an idea of something to go look up. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df['SUITEDET'] = df[df['SUITE'].isnull()]['DET']
condition = df['DET'].isin(usedet) | df['SUITE'].isin(usesuite)
df.loc[condition, 'SUITEDET'] = df['SUITE']
```

OUTPUT:

```
        SUITE      DET   SUITEDET
0       HISTO  HisRep2      HISTO
1       HISTO  HisRep3      HISTO
2         NaN    store      store
3         NaN   OnHold     OnHold
4        PMFA   Nemato       PMFA
5    bactmate   Nemato   bactmate
6      bacto1   abbac4     bacto1
7   abbadabba   BhyCPC  abbadabba
8      HAEMFF   pmbac3     HAEMFF
9      INCLIN    Trico     INCLIN
10     BOCOSP    isol1     BOCOSP
```

Solution 2:

```
condition = df['DET'].isin(usedet) | df['SUITE'].isin(usesuite)
df['SUITEDET'] = np.where(condition, df['SUITE'], np.where(df['SUITE'].isnull(), df['DET'], np.nan))
```